# DataGridRow border on top of DataGrid border

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to display DataGridRow border on top of DataGrid border. Is that even possible with a style or I have to use a custom adorner?

[image]

I want to achieve something like that:

[image]

I tried using `Panel.ZIndex` and `ClipToBounds="False"` but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="2,0,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    Text="!" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="DGR_Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    ClipToBounds="False"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <DataGridCellsPresenter
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />

                        <DataGridRowHeader
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}}" />
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NewItemMargin}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,-1,-1" />
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="123" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the stiffness of WPF it's not possible to use `Panel.ZIndex` that way as it can be used only on the same level. Few solutions to this problem:

- Custom adorner that draws selection rectangle for selected rows (must use adorner layer  above/on the same level of DataGrid border) custom template can be used to add `AdornerDecorator` just above the border.
- Add `Canvas` and `<Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRectangle" />` to DataGrid template, subclass DataGrid and change position of the Rectangle in Canvas based on the current selection in your subclassed DataGrid.

I'm not sure if there's any way to make this with style alone without subclassing DataGrid/adding event handlers to it, maybe with a custom converter that calculates position and size of selection rectangle and binding `Rectangle` properties using that converter.